# How to read Data from listView and not from adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an Android ListView, view which consists of 1 textview and 2 edittexts in each row:

```
  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/topic_id"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight"1"
       />  

  <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/topic_name"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="2" 
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="15sp"
      />

  <EditText 
      android:id="@+id/topic_description"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="4" 
      android:textSize="15sp"
      />
```

The user can write everything in the editTexts.
My question is how to get this text?

I mean I would like to have a method that gets a position of a row in the listView, and return the text inside the editTexts of this row.

This data does not exist in the adapter ofcourse, because the user **and not the adapter**, wrote the data in the editText.

If anyone can help I'll appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface for the communication between the adapter and the Activity/Fragment.

```
public interface OnEditingEndListener {
    void onDone(String editText);
}
```

The activity implements the onDone method which is triggered when an EditText receive the "on done edit" notification.
This event can be triggered with

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

            mListener.onDone(mEditText.getText().toString());

            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

where

```
 mListener
```

is a OnEditingEndListener property you pass in the adapter constructor:

```
public MyAdapter(OnEditingEndListener listener) {
   mListener = listener;
}
```

When the event occurs the listener will respond:

```
@Override
void onDone(String editText) {
   //do something with the text insert by the user
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you wrote (without the mlistener because I don't need the activity to be informed. My response to the event is in the adapter only -  I want to read the data and fill the arrayList, and this I can do from inside the adapter). The problem is that the event is not fired when I leave the editText.

Comment: You can chancge the if statement like this:
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) and you had to set the EditText in single-line mode mEditText.setSingleLine()). Works for me with this configuration

Comment: The problem is with the event "onEditorAction" - not with the if condition. The event is not activated by the editText Leaving.  Is there a way I can show you the code here?

Comment: try to add android:imeOptions="actionSend" in the EditText xml tag

Comment: No, it didn't change anything. Just to be clear, I write this "mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener().... "  inside the getView() of the custom adapter right? (With all the changes to my objects names ofcourse...)

Comment: Yes the place is right. Are you using the emulator or a device?